# using mail_to on a translation dependent string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to make a `mail_to` call with an email address which depends upon the current locale. I tried the following:

```
 =mail_to do
   =t 'language_dependent_email'
```

However I get an argument error from `mail_to` saying:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..3)
```

how can I call `t` on the string I would like to pass `mail_to` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I just had to write it like so:

```
=mail_to I18n.translate('language_dependent_email')
```